# Create an incoming webhook that posts to slack

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, slack

I am developing a bootstrap application and I would like to do the following:

when a form is submitted, I want an incoming webhook from Slack to post the contents of the form to a slack channel.

Because I am using bootstrap, how would I go about creating this?

Would I use Javascript or Node.js?

Comment: you need a server to listen for incoming webhooks so node. Bootstrap will be irrelevant here, its a css framework

Comment: could python also be used in this case? What's the difference between using node.js and python?

Comment: Python would work. anything that is a web server that 'always on' and listening for a POST or GET request to a certain URI

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this better. So python would be my backend framework?

Comment: If you wanted to use pyton, yes. There are 10's of different languages that are capable of serving http.
You could also use an AWS lambda function with a AWS API Endpoint if you didnt want to set up a server

Comment: As I understand it the question is not about creating a webhook, but using a existing webhook from Slack. See also my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways how to do that.

The standard approach is to use server based scripts. Your form calls a script on submit. In that script you read the form content on startup (e.g. input from GET request), build a Slack message out of it and send it to your [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) on your Slack team. That is most commonly done with PHP, but other server based script languages like Python, node.js should work just as well.

Check out [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) at W3School on how to read form data with PHP.

If you want to do it with Javascript you could attach your JS function to the submit event of your form, read the form content on submit, build a Slack message out of it and send it to your incoming webhook. I would use jQuery and AJAX for that, but it would also work with pure Javascript.

However, with Javascript you would have to expose the incoming webhook URL to the browser, which would potentially open your Slack team to SPAM. So I would suggest to stick with a server based solution.

Bootstrap is a set of CSS and Javascript that helps you make good looking and responsive websites, but does not have anything to do with sending form content to a webhook on Slack.

Comment: So, say I want to also alert the user that their form was successfully submitted, could two events take place at once when the submit button is pushed? Meaning, can I call the script and redirect the user to a new page?

Comment: Sure. By submitting the form the Webserver automatically opens a new page/script. On that script you can than send the form content to Slack and also have some output to inform the user e.g. A Bootstrap alert

Comment: @user2101463 If this answered your question please mark it as answered, thanks.